# asp.net mvc exclude css file from bundle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have such bundle

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/default/css")
       .IncludeDirectory("~/Content/themes/Default", "*.css"));
```

but I want to exclude one CSS file from it.

Is it possible to make this without specifying each CSS file in bundle?

Comment: Why dont you just move the css file out of that directory?

Comment: well of course i can do so and specify another bundle for this file, but it would be better to have all files in one directory and if i don't need it, i will just exclude it from bundle

Comment: Do you have a lot of files?  You could register each css individually if you have a small number of files.

Comment: i have about 20 files, but for example if i add new file to it i will need to register this file in bundle... and this way i could only exlude unnecessary and don't worry about names

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try using [IgnoreList.Ignore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.ignorelist.ignore(v=vs.110).aspx); `bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore(...)`.

Comment: For a nice example see: https://stack247.wordpress.com/2014/04/18/asp-net-mvc-4-bundles-ignore-list/

Comment: This is a poor answer. It doesn't explain how to use Ignore or how to access it. It's just a link to some poor documentation with a tiny snippet that explains none of the idiosyncrasies here. The comment about the wordpress site is the most useful thing here.

Answer (score 13):

An extension method could be what you need here:

```
public static class BundleExtentions
{
    public static Bundle IncludeDirectoryWithExclusion(this StyleBundle bundle, string directoryVirtualPath, string searchPattern, params string[] toExclude)
    {
        var folderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(directoryVirtualPath);

        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, searchPattern))
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Array.Find(toExclude, s => s.ToLower() == file.ToLower())))
            {
                continue;
            }     

            bundle.IncludeFile(directoryVirtualPath + "/" + file);
        }

        return bundle;
}
```

And then usage should be:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/default/css")
   .IncludeDirectoryWithExclusion("~/Content/themes/Default", "*.css", "file-you-dont-want.css"));
```

I'm not at a PC at the moment so the above is un-tested but should give you a template for your solution.

Comment: I have extended this answer to add search patterns and fix the shortcomings wrt to .min version here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36080620/1671558

Answer (score 4):

I have improved the good suggestion by Jon Malcolm (and some updates by Satpal [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18739040/1671558)) to fix few shortcomings that it had:

1) It breaks the default behavior of the bundles with ".min." files

2) It does not allow search patterns, but only files to be excluded

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;


public static class BundleExtentions
{
    public static Bundle IncludeDirectoryWithExclusion(this Bundle bundle, string directoryVirtualPath, string searchPattern, bool includeSubDirectories, params string[] excludePatterns)
    {
        string folderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(directoryVirtualPath);

        SearchOption searchOption = includeSubDirectories
                                        ? SearchOption.AllDirectories
                                        : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;

        HashSet<string> excludedFiles = GetFilesToExclude(folderPath, searchOption, excludePatterns);
        IEnumerable<string> resultFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, searchPattern, searchOption)
                                                    .Where(file => !excludedFiles.Contains(file) && !file.Contains(".min."));

        foreach (string resultFile in resultFiles)
        {
            bundle.Include(directoryVirtualPath + resultFile.Replace(folderPath, "")
                    .Replace("\\", "/"));
        }

        return bundle;
    }

    private static HashSet<string> GetFilesToExclude(string path, SearchOption searchOptions, params string[] excludePatterns)
    {
        var result = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (string pattern in excludePatterns)
        {
            result.UnionWith(Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern, searchOptions));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

An example usage that I have is to include all the libraries from the lib folder starting with angular, but excluding all the locale scripts (because only one will be added based on the language in a separate bundle later):

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/scripts")
                .Include("~/wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.js") // Has to be first
                .IncludeDirectoryWithExclusion("~/wwwroot/lib", "*.js", true, "*.locale.*.js"));
```

This will behave properly if you have both angular.min.js and angular.js and add unminified version in debug and using the existing .min.js in the release.

Comment: Thank you! This answer also solved an issue I was having with bundling.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another extension method that overloads the existing `IncludeDirectory` methods and supports searching subdirectories.

```
public static class BundleExtensions
{
    public static Bundle IncludeDirectory(
        this Bundle bundle,
        string directoryVirtualPath,
        string searchPattern,
        params string[] filesToExclude)
    {
        return IncludeDirectory(bundle, directoryVirtualPath, searchPattern, false, filesToExclude);
    }
    public static Bundle IncludeDirectory(
        this Bundle bundle,
        string directoryVirtualPath,
        string searchPattern,
        bool searchSubdirectories,
        params string[] filesToExclude)
    {
        var physicalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(directoryVirtualPath);
        return bundle.Include(Directory
            .EnumerateFiles(physicalPath, searchPattern, searchSubdirectories ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            .Select(physicalFileName => physicalFileName.Replace(physicalPath, directoryVirtualPath).Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar))
            .Where(virtualFileName => !filesToExclude.Contains(virtualFileName))
            .ToArray());
    }
}
```