# MVC4 bundling route exclusion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I make use of the bundling features in MVC4 by calling `bundles.EnableDefaultBundles();`, this allows me to browse to `http://website.com/content/css` which outputs a singular file of all the CSS files in the `/content` directory - great.

The issue is I have the following route which loads a blog post from the DB by title: `/post/{anything}` and in this case `{anything}` is `css` (for arguments sake, I can't change it) so the bundling is getting confused and trying to bundling everything in the `post` directory, which doesn't exist.

Is there any way to exclude a particular URL format or route from being bundled? I think not calling `EnableDefaultBundles()` would work but does that mean I would have to create bundles for everything manually?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990622/asp-net-mvc-exclude-css-file-from-bundle

Comment: I've tried the `IgnoreList` but it appears to only work for file names.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an old version of the Optimization package?  EnableDefaultBundles was removed prior to 1.0.  You can still accomplish the equivalent of that method by adding the equivalent js/css DynamicFolderBundles.

Comment: I'm using MVC4 RTM which reports v1.0.0.0.