# Ignoring a single file in the bundle

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization

Set up my bundles as follows:

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;

var scriptJquery = new ScriptBundle(Bundles.Scripts.Jquery, "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js")
    {
        CdnFallbackExpression = "window.jQuery",
    }
    .Include("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.js"); // {version} not work!

bundles.Add(scriptJquery);

var scriptBundle = new ScriptBundle(Bundles.Scripts.Common)
    {
        Orderer = new FileBundleOrderer(server.MapPath("~/Scripts/bundle.txt"))
    }
    .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts", "*.js", false);
bundles.Add(scriptBundle);
```

In my Scripts folder have the following structure.
**Note that the jQuery is on the same level as the others.**

[image: Folder JS Structure]

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@Scripts.Render(CreditoImobiliarioBB.Web.App_Start.Bundles.Scripts.Jquery)
@Scripts.Render(CreditoImobiliarioBB.Web.App_Start.Bundles.Scripts.Common)
```

When running the application the following scripts are generated.
Note that the **jQuery appeared twice!**

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>    <!--  <------ -->

<script src="/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/moment.pt-br.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/handlebars.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/accounting.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.pnotify.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/fileuploader.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.inputmask.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.inputmask.numeric.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.inputmask.date.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.maskMoney.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.bootpag.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Email.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Endereco.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Telefone.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/prototypes.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/antiForgetyTokenHelper.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/ajaxPost.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/ajaxUploader.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>   <!--  <------ -->
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/scripts.js"></script>
```

If I try to ignore the jQuery file, it does not appear in any way!

```
bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("jquery-{version}.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
```

**How to ignore the jQuery in a single bundle only? In case the Bundles.Scripts.Common**

Comment: You could try Jon Malcolm's answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990622/asp-net-mvc-exclude-css-file-from-bundle

Comment: @SteveTemple Its Helps. I was thinking something like `Exclude = "jquery.{version}*.js"`.

Comment: You could, modify the extension method listed in the above url

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking Adam, you should be able to take that extension and tweak it to do what you need

Comment: +1 for the insane arrow.

Answer (score 3):

I have extended @Jon Malcolm answer to solve my problem.

```
public static class BundleExtentions
{
    public static Bundle IncludeDirectoryWithExclusion(this ScriptBundle bundle, string directoryVirtualPath, string searchPattern, bool includeSubDirectories, params string[] toExclude)
    {
        var folderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(directoryVirtualPath);
        SearchOption searchOption = includeSubDirectories
                                        ? SearchOption.AllDirectories
                                        : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;

        foreach (var file in from file in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, searchPattern, searchOption) let fileName = Path.GetFileName(file) where String.IsNullOrEmpty(Array.Find(toExclude, s => fileName != null && s.ToLower() == fileName.ToLower())) select file)
        {
            bundle.Include(directoryVirtualPath + file.Replace(folderPath, string.Empty).Replace("\\", "/"));
        }

        return bundle;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
 mybundle.IncludeDirectoryWithExclusion("~/Directory", "*.js", true, "excluejsfile.js");
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: I have improved this code even further to add exclusion patterns and proper .min handling here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36080620/1671558