# Excluding Certain Files from ASP.NET MVC Bundler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundler

What is the best way to have the ASP.NET MVC Bundler exclude files with the backup_ prefix in front of the name of the file?

I want to use the code:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/siteStyles")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/Content/Stylesheets/","*.css", true)
        );
```

but I want to be able to get it to ignore a file in the same directory backup_style.css. I would prefer to not have to call the file style.css.backup because I want to keep the file for reference and maintain the syntax highlighting. What is the best way to add this exclusion?

Comment: Try using bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore(...)

As quoted from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990622/asp-net-mvc-exclude-css-file-from-bundle

Comment: Duplicate question. [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990622/asp-net-mvc-exclude-css-file-from-bundle)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net mvc exclude css file from bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990622/asp-net-mvc-exclude-css-file-from-bundle)