# ASP.net bundle.IncludeDirectory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, bundling-and-minification

I know that you can include all .js files from directory like

```
.IncludeDirectory("~/Content/js", "*.js");
```

but how do I exclude a file from this search pattern? I have a example.js in this said directory which I wouldn't like to include with this *.js pattern, is there any good way to do it?

Comment: See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990622/asp-net-mvc-exclude-css-file-from-bundle)

Comment: Try using IgnoreList.Ignore; bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore(...).